# powerbi create datasource api for IBM netezza

Tags: api, datasource, powerbi, netezza

what are the correct parameters to be entered in the JSON body while sending post API request?

this is what is given in their documentation:

```
{
"name": "IBM Netezza Data Source",
"connectionDetails": "{"server":"MQPDAQ01.AM.LILLY.COM", "database":"GMDM_STG_QAR"}",
"type": "ODBC",    
"credentialDetails": {
    "credentials": "ABEF==",        
    "encryptionAlgorithm": "RSA-OAEP",
      "encryptedConnection": "Encrypted|NotEncrypted",
    "privacyLevel": "None|Public|Organizational|Private",
    "credentialType": "Basic|Windows|Anonymous|…"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Generally I would advise you to use odbc to connect from powerbi to netezza, as far as I know the ‘native’ connect won’t let you override the sql and thus you will never ‘group by’ or filter data going out of netezza. That will ensure poor performance for the end user and a long running query that allocates vital resources in netezza for no use.

The ‘wizard’ for odbc fills out those Json connect strings nicely in my experience:)